# How to solve Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! in a directive after upgrading angularjs to 1.8.0 version

Tags: angularjs

I came across `Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported`  issue after upgrading angularJS from 1.5.11 to 1.8.0 in a huge project. Basically, I also upgraded angular-ui-router (0.4.3 version) and the dependencies associated with angularJS to 1.8.0 too (e.g. angular-sanitize, angular- animate, etc). However, I've struggled hours debugging the error.

I isolated a simple case where the error is presented. Essentially, there is a component that consumes a directive and when the directive is rendered, appears this [ng:cpws] issue (several times).

A basic directive code is:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import * as templateText from 'text!./panel-description.html';
export { templateText };
export const moduleName = 'panelDescription';
export class PanelDescriptionDirective implements ng.IDirective {
  restrict = 'E';
  scope = {
    data: '=',
  };
  template = templateText;
}
angular.module(moduleName, [])
  .directive('panelDescription', ['$injector', ($injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService) => {
    return $injector.instantiate(PanelDescriptionDirective);
  }]);
```

The directive HTML file is:

```
<div id="descForm">
  <label for="panel-description">Label</label>
  <textarea id="panel-description"
            name="panelDescription"
            ng-model="data">
  </textarea>
```

The component HTML file:

```
<div>
  <form>
          <div>
          <panel-description data="contentCreateItem.body"></panel-description>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I remove `ng-model` property from the `textarea` element, the error disappears. I don't understand what is the clear relationship between copying scopes and windows with this directive. Before upgrading angular, this flow worked without any issue.